# display data in html through an AJAX success method

Tags: jquery, python, html, ajax, flask

i am writing the below code for displaying data in html table returned from database in json format

```
success : function(data){
            alert("declaring variable");
            var output="<table id=tableStyle>";
            alert("creating output");
            output+="<tr>" + "<th>" + "REPORTSUITE_ID" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "REPORTSUITE_NAME" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "STAGING_DATABASE" + "</th>" + "<th>" + "DWH_DATABASE" + "</th>" + "</tr>";
            alert("starting for loop"); 
            for (var i in data)
            {
                output+="<tr>" + "<td>" + data[i].REPORTSUITE_ID + "</td>" + "<td>" + 
      "<button>"+data[i].REPORTSUITE_NAME + "</button>" +
      "</td>" + "<td>" + data[i].STAGING_DATABASE + "</td>" + "<td>" + data[i].DWH_DATABASE + "</td>" + "</tr>";
            }
            output+="</table>";
            alert ("displaying now ");
            document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
          }
```

The data format in JSON is as follows:

```
[{"DWH_DATABASE": "abc", "REPORTSUITE_ID": 51, "REPORTSUITE_NAME": "C1","STAGING_DATABASE": "def", "TRANS_TABLE": "T1"}, 
{"DWH_DATABASE": "abc", "REPORTSUITE_ID": 49, "REPORTSUITE_NAME": "C2", "STAGING_DATABASE": "def", "TRANS_TABLE": "T2"}, 
{"DWH_DATABASE":"abc", "REPORTSUITE_ID": 40, "REPORTSUITE_NAME": "C3", "STAGING_DATABASE": "def", "TRANS_TABLE": "T3"}]
```

When i execute the above code, i get the result as follows:

```
REPORTSUITE_ID  REPORTSUITE_NAME    STAGING_DATABASE    DWH_DATABASE
undefined         undefined          undefined         undefined
undefined         undefined          undefined         undefined
undefined         undefined          undefined         undefined
```

Please tell me how to display the data correctly

Comment: Is your `data` argument sill a JSON string or is it already parsed into a Javascript object?

Comment: i think inside the loop you should acces the data by `i` like `i.DWH_DATABASE` not `data[i].DWH_DATABASE`

Comment: It's pretty hard to help you when aren't hanging around here to promptly answer questions we ask.

Comment: I tried i.DWH_DATABASE, still the same output. . I did      "alert(data)" and it displayed in the JSON format. The output i viewed on alert is as given above in the question but when i try to parse it i get all undefineds

Comment: I got the proper output. I did data = JSON.parse(data); and then ,for displaying i did data[i].REPORTSUITE_ID. it worked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to parse the json first so you can deal with it as an object not a text using the following code as the first line of the success method:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: I already tried this thing but i am still getting the same output

Answer (score 0):

code is correct, but make sure the data variable actually contains the data. print it out through the console beforehand and You'll see what's inside:

```
console.log("data:" + data);
```

Comment: i did alert on data and it alerts with the correct data, so data is being returned